# OggStreamer-Thread class (to play music in my game) only works 1/3 of the time

Tags: java, stream, ogg

First of all, I love you guys! This is THE best site for finding answers to weird and difficult programming questions. This is the first problem I have not been able to find a solution for on this site, so thanks for that.

So, I have a runnable Game.class and a runnable OggStreamer.class, to allow the music to run in its own separate thread, which I send as a parameter for the Game-class to use. When I run the game from my IDE the OggStreamer always works, but when I've exported it to a .jar-file, it only works 1/3 of the times I start it up. And it's not like the first piece of music doesn't start, and then the next piece of music started will play..it doesn't work at all, until I've started the game a few times.

Has any of you good people had a similar problem? I could understand it if it didn't work at all, which could indicate there was something wrong with the file-references to the music inside the jar-file...but it DOES work, just not consistently.

NOTE: This is my first attempt at Game-programming, and I know it's not very pretty and that I am a total newbie :) There are many things I'd change about the general design, but I'm using this as a project to help me understand the problems I'll encounter when I sit down to design a real framework for my next game.

Start.class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Game game = new Game(musicStreamer);
game.init(); // loads stuff
threadExecutor.execute( musicStreamer ); // start task1
threadExecutor.execute( game ); // start task2
threadExecutor.shutdown();
}
```

OggStreamer.class

```
public class OggStreamer implements Runnable{

private URL url;
private AudioInputStream stream;
private AudioInputStream decodedStream;
private AudioFormat format;
private AudioFormat decodedFormat;
private boolean stop, running;
String filename = "";
SourceDataLine line = null;

public OggStreamer() {
    this.stop = true;
    this.running = true;
    this.url = null;
}

public void run() {
    while(running){
            while (!this.stop) {
                System.out.println("Playing Loop");
                try {
                    // Get AudioInputStream from given file.
                    this.stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.url);
                    this.decodedStream = null;
                    if (this.stream != null) {
                        this.format = this.stream.getFormat();
                        this.decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(
                                AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                                this.format.getSampleRate(), 16,
                                this.format.getChannels(),
                                this.format.getChannels() * 2,
                                this.format.getSampleRate(), false);
                        // Get AudioInputStream that will be decoded by underlying
                        // VorbisSPI
                        this.decodedStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                                this.decodedFormat, this.stream);
                    }else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Stream = null!");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Do nothing
                    System.out.println("Could not get or decode audiostream");
                }
                line = null;
                try {
                    line = this.getSourceDataLine(this.decodedFormat);
                    FloatControl volume = (FloatControl)line.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
                    volume.setValue(1);
                } catch (LineUnavailableException lue) {
                    // Do nothing
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Line is unavailable!");
                }
                if (line != null) {
                    try {
                        byte[] data = new byte[4096];
                        // Start
                        line.start();
                        int nBytesRead = 0;

                        while (nBytesRead != -1) {
                            nBytesRead = this.decodedStream.read(data, 0,
                                    data.length);
                            if (nBytesRead != -1) {
                                line.write(data, 0, nBytesRead);
                            }
                            if (this.stop) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        // Stop
                        line.drain();
                        line.stop();
                        line.close();
                    } catch (IOException io) {
                        // Do nothing
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Line cannot start!");
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

private SourceDataLine getSourceDataLine(AudioFormat audioFormat)
        throws LineUnavailableException {
    SourceDataLine res = null;
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class,
            audioFormat);
    res = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    res.open(audioFormat);
    return res;
}


public void startLoop(String filenameString) {
    this.filename = filenameString;
    System.out.println("Starting loop with: "+filenameString);
    this.url = this.getClass().getResource(filenameString);
    this.stop = false;
}

public void stopLoop() {
    System.out.println("Stopping loop");
    try {
        if(this.decodedStream!=null)this.decodedStream.close();
        if(this.stream!=null)this.stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    this.stop = true;
    this.url = null;
}

public boolean isStop() {
    return stop;
}

public void setStop(boolean stop) {
    this.stop = stop;
}

public URL getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String string) {
    this.filename = string;
    this.url = this.getClass().getResource(string);
}

public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
}
}
```

Game.class uses the OggStreamer-class as such:

```
if(musicStreamer!=null && !musicStreamer.getFilename().equals("/snm/sound/oggs/Prelude.ogg")){
            if(!musicStreamer.isStop())musicStreamer.stopLoop();
            musicStreamer.startLoop("/snm/sound/oggs/Prelude.ogg");
}
```